# $Tor_1^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: tensor-products, derived-functors

How do I find $Tor_1^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$? and is it free or at least projective?

I tried using the obvious short exact sequence then tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ from either side, but I still need help.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding (1), what is the tensor product if _not_ a $\mathbb{Z}$-module...??

Comment: @ZhenLin Yeah it's an abelian group; my bad! Anyway,    $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, right?

Comment: Yes. So that's $\mathrm{Tor}_0$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks... Now for $Tor_1^\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ it's the kernel of the map $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} 2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $ but I'm not sure how to make it more rigorous...

Comment: Advice: Compute $Tor^R_1(R/I,M)$ in general.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Well yeah.. I should consider the short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow  I \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0$ then tensor with $M$ which tells me that $Tor_1^R(R/I,M) $ is the kernel of $i \otimes 1_M$; but it's this particular case I can't seem to figure out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long exact sequence associated to $0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$ is

$0 \to Tor_1(R/I,M) \to I \otimes M \to M \to M/I \to 0.$

Hence, $Tor_1(R/I,M)$ is the kernel of $I \otimes M \to M$. If $M=R/J$, this map identifies with $I/IJ \to R/J$, so that $Tor_1(R/I,R/J) = (I \cap J)/(IJ)$.

If $R$ is a PID, we can write $I=(a)$, $J=(b)$, this shows easily $Tor_1(R/(a),R/(b)) \cong R/(\mathrm{ggT}(a,b))$.

Comment: Thanks! So, $Tor_1^\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} ,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is neither projective nor injective as a  $\mathbb{Z} $-module, right? I ask this because I have a short exact sequence, $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ and I need to find A!